# How do I get the error code from pthread_join()?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, errno, pthread-join

The following code fails to join pthreads and the message "join failed" is printed. How do I get more information about the failure and its cause?

```
pthread_t aThread[MAX_LENGTH];
    int errCode[MAX_LENGTH];
    char returnVal;    
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
    {

        if((errCode[i] = pthread_create(&aThread[i], NULL, &findMatch, &fpArgs)) != 0)
            printf("error creating thread %d\n", errCode[i]);
        if(!pthread_join(aThread[i], (void**)&returnVal))
            printf("join failed\n i is %d", i);
    }
```

**EDIT:** actually join returned `no error` and I made a mistake. The if statment shouldn't have the `!` because join returns a non-zero number if there is a problem which evaluates to true.

Comment: Your cast of your `returnVal` address to a `void**` is **undefined behavior**. Unless `sizeof(char) == sizeof(void*)` on your system (which I can all-but-guarantee you it is *not*) It doesn't look like you're using it anyway, and NULL is a viable option, so you may rather just `pthread_join(aThread[i], NULL);` Further, `pthread_join` returns zero (0) **on success**, so testing it for failure with `!` is backwards. Finally, you don't want to do it this way anyway, you want to start them all, *then* join them all. What you have here is literally no better than single threaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pointed this out in comment, but it deserves amplification.

**Your `returnVal` usage is wrong**

The `pthread_join` api expects a `void**`, that is a pointer to a `void*`. Unlike `void*`, a `void**` is not equally universal. It is a pointer of specific type and as such you should only pass a likewise typed address. However, you're not using it anyway, so I would suggest for now you simply pass NULL. As-written, it is **undefined behavior**. And I can all-but-guarantee you `sizeof(char)`, the writable size of the address you giving it, and `sizeof(void*)`, the size it expects to have available, are *not* the same. Consider this instead for now:

```
pthread_join(aThread[i], NULL);
```

In case you're wondering what the use for that `void**` parameter is, it is a place to store  `void*` return value from your thread-proc. Recall a pthread thread-proc looks like this:

```
void* thread_proc(void* args)
// ^----- this is what is stashed in the pthread_join second parameter
```

---

**You're logic for failure testing is backwards**

The `pthread_join` function returns `0` on *success*; not on failure.

---

**You're not actually running concurrent threads**

Thread concurrency simply means your threads run *simultaneously*. But yours do not. You start a thread, then wait for it to end, then start a thread, then wait for it to end, etc. This is literally no better (and in fact, actually *worse*) than simply calling a function. If you want your threads to run *concurrently* your logic should be styled like this:

```
pthread_t aThread[MAX_LENGTH];
int errCode[MAX_LENGTH] = {0};

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
{
    if((errCode[i] = pthread_create(&aThread[i], NULL, &findMatch, &fpArgs)) != 0)
        printf("error creating thread %d, error=%d\n", i, errCode[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
{
    // note the check for errCode[i], which is only non-zero 
    //  if the i'th thread failed to start
    if(errCode[i] == 0)
    {
        errCode[i] = pthread_join(aThread[i], NULL))
        if (errCode[i] != 0)
            printf("error joining thread %d, error=%d\n", i, errCode[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When the function fails (i.e. in any pthread call, a return code that is not equal to zero) it will set `errno` to the value of the reason for failure.  There are a couple of ways to get the textual explanation of failure code.

```
int returnval;

if((returnval = pthread_join(aThread[i], (void**)&returnVal)) != 0)
{
    printf("error joining thread: %s\n", strerror(returnval));  //1st optiop

    perror("error joining thread:");  //2nd option

    printf("error joining thread: %m\n");  //3rd option

}
```

(1) `strerror` will print the error string of the error value you pass it and is convenient for placing in printf statements.

(2) `perror` allows you to pass a little string that will print first and then it will automatically print the error description of whatever value `errno` is set to.  You don't need to explicitly pass `errno`.

(3) There is a glibc extension to `printf` that provide a `%m` conversion specifier that acts like `strerror` but with a little less muss and fuss.  This would be the least portable.

Once you get the description you can easily look into the man pages of the call that failed and they will provide greater hints as to why the call failed.  Charlie Burns has posted the reasons `pthread_join` might fail.

Comment: You _can_ assign the return value of your call to `pthread_join` to `errno` but I don't think the pthread library does this automatically for you. So your first paragraph is wrong. You can use the `returnval` as it was `errno` so the rest of your answer looks correct. (-1)

Comment: Not entirely correct, `pthread_join` doesn't have to set `errno`. I stumbled upon this page because *(on ancient Ubuntu 18.04)* `pthread_join` returns non-zero, but `perror()` just prints `Success`. Looking at `man pthread_join`, it has no mention of `errno` whatsoever, instead it says that `pthread_join` returns an error number. And there's an answer on this page since 2020 that says the same, so I guess I'm not alone to be mislead by this annoying pthread inconsistency *(as compared to other library functions)*.

Comment: Ah, sorry, there's already an old comment pointing that out. Okay, I'll do ⁻¹ until this answer is edited then.

Answer (score 1):

The pthread library does not set the **errno** variable upon error. The error code is returned by the function instead.
The online manual under Linux is quite clear for the pthread functions (e.g. [man pthread_join](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html)) as the "RETURN VALUE" section generally contains something like:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> On success, pthread_join() returns 0; on error, it returns an error number.

If you need to output the error through functions like **strerror()**, **strerror_r()** or **%m** printf format ([the latter is a GLIBC extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20577557/14393739)), you must use the return code of the failing service or update **errno** in the error branch:

```
if ((rc = pthread_join(...)) != 0) {
  errno = rc;
  fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join(): %m\n");
 OR
  fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join(): %m\n", strerror(errno)); // rc could be used without errno
 OR
  char err_buf[128];
  errno = rc;
  fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join(): %m\n", strerror_r(errno, err_buf, sizeof(err_buf))); // rc could be used without errno
```

**Notes**:

- **errno** is thread-safe (it is located in the thread local storage). So, it is local to each thread
- **strerror_r()** and **%m** should be used in multi-threaded environment as they are thread-safe (**strerror()** is not)

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that `man pthread_create` even has an example of usage, where a macro `handle_error_en()` is created, whose code is basically just using a pthread return value, and printing an error by transforming this value to `errno`.

Comment: Just found out: `man 7 pthreads` claims that none of the pthreads functions set `errno`. Quoting: `Note that the pthreads functions do not set errno`.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? The return value tells you the error:

RETURN VALUES
     If successful,  the pthread_join() function will return zero.  Otherwise,
     an error number will be returned to indicate the error.

ERRORS
     pthread_join() will fail if:

```
 [EDEADLK]          A deadlock was detected or the value of thread speci-
                    fies the calling thread.

 [EINVAL]           The implementation has detected that the value speci-
                    fied by thread does not refer to a joinable thread.

 [ESRCH]            No thread could be found corresponding to that speci-
                    fied by the given thread ID, thread.
```

Comment: How do you get it to printout which of those it is? For example `joinErr = pthread_join(aThread[i], &returnVal);
            printf("join returned %d\n", joinErr);` always is 0

Comment: @Celeritas always zero means it *succeeded*; not failed.

Answer (score 0):

More specifically::

```
int retVal = pthread_create(&myThread, NULL,myThreadFn, NULL);
printf("error joining thread: %d\n", retVal);
```