# What's the meaning of the %m formatting specifier?

Tags: c, printf, glibc, errno, format-specifiers

The output for this code printed out ‘Success’.

```
printf("%m\n");
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`m` conversion specifier is not C but is a GNU extension to `printf`:

From GNU documentation:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Other-Output-Conversions.html

> The ‘%m’ conversion prints the string corresponding to the error code in errno. See Error Messages. Thus:
>
> ```
> fprintf (stderr, "can't open `%s': %m\n", filename);
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> fprintf (stderr, "can't open `%s': %s\n", filename, strerror (errno));
> ```
>
> The ‘%m’ conversion is a GNU C Library extension.

So:

```
printf("%m\n", d);
```

is equivalent to

```
printf("%s\n", strerror (errno), d);
```

which is equivalent to

```
printf("%s\n", strerror (errno));
```

Note that `%m`does not require an argument. Here `printf("%m\n", d)` and `printf("%s\n", strerror (errno), d)` have more arguments than required: with `printf` if there are extra trailing arguments, they are just evaluated and ignored.

Comment: I think the most interesting part is the fact that printf does *not* require an extra parameter for each `%m`.

Comment: Strerror() is not thread-safe but %m is.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, the manual of [printf()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) concerning **%m** is quite laconic:

```
m      (Glibc extension; supported by uClibc and musl.)  Print output
              of strerror(errno).  No argument is required.
```

But `strerror()` is not multi-thread safe: it is not reentrant. The thread-safe version is [strerror_r()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html).

A little study of the [GLIBC implementation](http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/percent_m.html) shows that **%m** is actually equivalent to strerror_r() and not to strerror(). Hence **%m is thread-safe**! The online manual is consequently wrong (or at least not accurate enough)!